# Why should i update a java jdk 1.6 web application and what is the risk to not do it?

Tags: java, web-services, security, web

Today i received a request to make a plan to update an web application deployed in a tomcat 7 to Java 1.8 and the reason was the web site security.

So i would like to know if is really important to update our web application  to java 1.8 and the real problems if we keep our server using java 1.6 deployed in a tomcat 7 ?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest risk is probably not for your application. The risk from your customer's perspective is that the Java 6 runtime is vulnerable to *many* things. If your application only supports Java 6, they need to have that on their workstations, which they don't want to, because it makes their workstations vulnerable.

Your app may also be vulnerable if running on Java 6, see the list of updates [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_6_updates) for example. It depends whether you are using any API that had a security vulnerability since then. But my guess is your customer is primarily worried about their workstations.

Comment: since our web application is inside a container (tomcat 7) our clients do not need java installed in their computer to use our API.

Comment: Got it, sorry for that. Honestly, i don't know why i thought otherwise. It's still the second paragraph then, but you are right in that your application is not _necessarily_ vulnerable I think, there's just a higher chance. You can for example provide your customer a 3rd party penetration test and/or code scan report showing it's all ok (if it is) to try and persuade them.

Comment: Ok, i ll run openVAS and nessus agaist our server in order to try to persuade them :)

Answer (score 1):

Most java 1.6 code should compile and be fine with version 1.8 of java.
Things what are already marked as deprecated in java 1.6 (or earlier) may have been removed from a later release (1.7 or 1.8).  Any of these will be obvious if you just compile your existing code with a java 1.8 compiler.

As mentioned in another answer, security risks of java 1.6 are a good reason to upgrade.  Also versions 1.7 and earlier are already officially end-of-lifed by Oracle so only version 1.8 gets public security updates.  It is possible to get a subscription to for java 1.7 security updates from Oracle.  I'm not sure if there is one available for any other versions of java.

Another concern may be "is there a java 1.8 version of my JEE container."
1.8 has been out for a while so I suspect that the answer is "yes".

Here is the Oracle [Compatibility Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html)

Comment: since our web application is inside a container (tomcat 7) our clients do not need java installed in their computer to use our API.

Answer (score 0):

Last **JDK 1.6** and **JDK 1.8** update in 2016-07-19. All platform supported now but only Java 8 have public security updates. It's a good reason for update your jre/jdk. Java 8 support most feature of Java 6, you don't have problem with compilation. But some of methods be deprecated.

The conclusion is that we need to use technologies that are supported by 
the developer to the full.